# Cannot include file in release mode

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

My project runs perfectly in debug mode. I tried compiling it in release mode, but `cannot include file error` came. I used relative paths to include the header file. But surprisingly it was not an issue of wrong path as it could go to the level above the header file.

For example: If header file is in relative path `..\..\..\..\xyz\hdr`
Files in folder `hdr` cannot be compiled, but if I keep files in folder `xyz` it gets compiled. This problem is faced only in release mode in visual studio.

I hope I am clear with my question!

Has anyone faced such problems? How to overcome this?

Comment: Compare project settings in Debug and Release configurations.

Comment: @AlexFarber The settings are the same. While trying all combinations, I found it can reach the folder above where the file is kept. The directories are correct as it can reach the folder above

Answer (score 3):

AS hinted in the comment, this is almost certainly a difference between your debug and release setup. There is a settings tab for "include directories" in your Visual Studio. Select debug build, find the include directories (under "compiler settings", I think, but it's been a while and I no longer use VS2005, so can't go check it). Copy the content there, and then find the same thing for your release build and paste it in there. Should solve your problem.

Comment: The settings are the same. While trying all combinations, I found it can reach the folder above where the file is kept. The directories are correct as it can reach the folder above

Comment: @user1692342 I know it's been a long time but I face this problem now and the answer was in different settings of project. The difference was in Project->Properties->C/C++->General and  Project->Properties->Linker->General